# Recursively change Date Modified property of Folder to match that of file inside

Tags: regex, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a number of folders, each with files inside the folder.

The structure looks something like this:

```
Folder.No.1
Folder_No_2
Folder No 3
```

and the files within are something like:

```
Folder.No.1\My.Movie.1.avi
Folder.No.1\My.Movie.1.txt

Folder_No_2\My_Movie_2.avi
Folder_No_2\My_Movie_2.jpg
Folder_No_2\My_Movie_2.txt

Folder No 3\My Movie 3.avi
```

As you can see, some folders contain . in the name, some contain _ and some use spaces.

The one consistent factor is that each folder will *always* contain an .avi file, regardless of anything else.

Therefore, how can I change the `Date Modified` date/time of the folder to match that of the .avi file contained within the folder?

Is there some way I can do this using a batch file?

Thanks for any help!

If this question already has an answer (using command line batch script) please direct me to it as I have looked at many answers but cannot find a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily done by iterating over the "Folder*" directories, identify a ".avi" file, and setting the directory `LastWriteTime` to that of the ".avi' file. I have not tested this, but it should provide a good starting point.

=== Set-FolderToAviTime.ps1

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param()
$BaseDir = 'C:\src\t\redatedirs'    # Directory containing 'Folder*' directories
$DirMask = 'Folder*'                # 'Folder*'
$DirHash = @{}
Get-ChildItem -Path $BaseDir -Filter $DirMask |
    Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } |
    ForEach-Object {
        Write-Verbose "Working on directory $($_.FullName)"
        $Dir = Get-Item -Path $_.FullName
        if (-not (Test-Path -Path "$_\*" -Filter '*.avi')) {
            Write-Verbose -Message "No .avi file in $($Dir.fullname)"
        }
        Get-ChildItem -Path "$_\*" -Filter '*.avi' |
            Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
            Select-Object -First 1 |
            ForEach-Object {
                Write-Verbose "Using .avi file $($_.FullName)"
                $DirHash[$Dir] = $_.LastWriteTime
            }
    }
$DirHash.Keys | ForEach-Object { $_.LastWriteTime = $DirHash[$_] }
```

=== Set-FolderToAviTime.bat

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ".\redatedirs.ps1 -Verbose"
```

Comment: I have revised how the directory information is gotten. Please try again.

Comment: `Select-Object` is there to ensure that there is only one (1) .avi file used. I do not think `Get-Member` will be useful there. What version of PowerShell is in use? What is the output from the command `powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()"`?

Comment: This turned out to be a semi-interesting problem. It appears that while the directory was an object inside the pipeline, that it could not be changed. The code now saves the directories to change and the timestamp from the .avi file into a hash. The last line does the actual changing of the directory LastWriteTime.

Comment: Did you try the current code in the answer? PS 3 will require some changes. It works on my Windows 7 system running PS 5.1.

Comment: The code is revised again to run on PS 3. I have tested this and it is working on my machine. Windows 7, PS 5.1.

Comment: Can you add something so I can see verbose output to determine what it is doing? There must be something a little more to this, such as changing a group policy or administrative setting to allow Date Modified to be overwritten.

Comment: Revised again. Be sure to change the first two variables, `$BaseDir` and `$DirMask` to be what you want. You can add more `Write-Verbose` statements or step through the code with the ISE or Microsoft Code editor.

Comment: Got It - $DirMask = 'dir*' on Line 4 is better changed to $DirMask = '*' to catch everything. One other thing about Verbose though... is it possible to add an "Else" line that also outputs a comment such as "No avi found in folder" when a folder is empty or does not contain an .avi file? This would only happen if I had made some mistake moving my files into folders, but better to cover it if it is possible.

Comment: Revised yet again. You can also make changes and enhancements.

Comment: All good now - great job!

Comment: If this is working for you, please click on the check mark to indicate to others that this is the accepted answer.